# Avoid Warnings during Jacobian Matrix Calculation

Tags: python, warnings, lstm, gradient, gradienttape

I have a trained LSTM model. I would like to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the output w.r.t input. I have written the following code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('filename')
a = data[:20]       #shape is (20,5)
b = data[50:70]     #shape is (20,5)  
A = [a,b]           #shape is (2,20,5)

At = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, np.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True,watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape:

 tape.watch(At)
 y1 = model(At)
 
jacobian=tape.jacobian(y1,At)
```

I got the desired output but I am getting some warnings which I cannot understand. If its for one time that is ok to let them be. But I need to calculate the Jacobian matrix in a for loop which runs over 1000 times. So these warnings are appearing in each iteration of the for loop.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x000002A6E0129CA8> could not be transformed 
and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutgoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the 
verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: 
converting <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x000002A6E0129CA8>: AssertionError: Bad argument number for 
Name: 3, expecting 4

WARNING: Entity <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x000002A6E0129CA8> could not be transformed and will be 
executed as-is. Please report this to the AutgoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 
10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting 
<function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x000002A6E0129CA8>: AssertionError: Bad argument number for Name: 3, 
expecting 4
```

These are the two warnings that appear continuously during the for loop implementation. Can anyone help me out with either correcting my code or give me a trick to avoid these warnings?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution with the help of my friend.

```
pip install -U gast==0.2.2.
```

Install this and this will make sure that the above warnings do not appear.